# Algorithm to generate Rhombic sphere tiling

Tags: geometry, algorithms, spheres

I want to make a function for generate generic [Rhombic triacontahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_triacontahedron) and any level of detail of rhombic sphere tiling

I want to know that can we use rhombic face to tile sphere in more detail than Rhombic triacontahedron? And how can we calculate the point or position of each?

Or is there any easier algorithm, such as try to make pair from the geodesic?

Comment: Couldn't you just partition each rhombus into $n\times n$ smaller rhombi?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for an easy way. but I want more regular looking of face to scatter in whole sphere, Like a hexagon geodesic

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen OH, by rethinking with your comment, now I have easy solution. I should ask about algorithm to make hexagon tiling then revert it to rhombic. Should I change my question though?